# backbone get error, adress book tutorial

Tags: backbone.js

I'm doing this backbone tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsEw2i4wQMM

, but I got stuck with some server side issues, namely the GET and PUT functions.

I've uploaded the following files to my server: https://github.com/thomasdavis/video-backbone-beginner-server

my demo site is http://mywebbdesigner.com/adressbook/index.html

the console logs a 404 Get error for the user id routes

my PUT function logs the items, but doesn't save them.

I don't know what I'm missing..
please if you can help, check network and console logs

thanks for the help!

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>adressbook</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
        <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


       <section class="container simpel-adressbook">
            <h1 class="app-title"><a href="#">Adressbook</a></h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contents container"></div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
            <article class="span5 user-list">
            <h2>Contact list:</h2>
                <ul>
                <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
                    <li> 
                        <a href="">  <!--// #/users/<%= user.id %>-->
                            <span><%= user.get('firstname') %></span>
                            <span><%= user.get('lastname') %></span>
                            <span><%= user.get('age') %></span>
                            <span><a href=" #/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn"> Edit </a></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <% }); %>
                </ul>
                <a href="#/new" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till</a>
            </article>
            <article class="span5">
                <h2>Contact details:</h2>
                <div class="details"></div>
            </article>
        </script>

        <script type="text/template" id="edit-user-template">
            <div class="container">
                <article class="span5">
                    <form class="edit-user-form">
                        <legend><%= user ? 'Updte' : 'Create' %> User</legend>
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%= user ? user.get('firstname') : '' %>"></input>
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<%= user ? user.get('lastname') : '' %>"></input>
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="text" name="age" value="<%= user ? user.get('age') : '' %>"></input>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Create user</button>
                    </form>
                </article>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/template" id="user-details-template">
        <h2>Contact details:</h2>
            <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
                <p>
                    <span><%= user.get('firstname') %></span>
                    <span><%= user.get('lastname') %></span>
                    <span><%= user.get('adress') %></span>
                    <span><%= user.get('postcode') %></span>
                    <span><%= user.get('city') %></span>
                </p>
            <% }); %>
            <a href="#/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till</a>
        </script>

        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <!--script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script-->
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>

        <script>
            $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                options.url = 'http://mywebbdesigner.com/adressbook' + options.url;
            });

            $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
              var o = {};
              var a = this.serializeArray();
              $.each(a, function() {
                  if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                      if (!o[this.name].push) {
                          o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                      }
                      o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                  } else {
                      o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                  }
              });
              return o;
            };


            var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: '/users'
            });
            var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
                urlRoot: '/users'
            });

            var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.contents',
                render: function () {
                    var that = this;
                    var users = new Users();
                    users.fetch({
                        success: function (users) {
                            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models});
                            that.$el.html(template);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.contents',
                render: function (options) {
                    var that = this;
                    if(options.id) {
                        var user = new User({id: options.id});
                        user.fetch({
                            success: function (user) {
                                var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user: user});
                                that.$el.html(template);
                            }
                        })
                    } else {    
                    var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user: null});
                    this.$el.html(template);
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser'
                }, 
                saveUser: function(ev) {
                    var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
                    var user = new User();
                    user.save(userDetails, {
                        success: function (user) {
                            router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
                            console.log(user);
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                }
            });
            var UserInfo = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.details',
                render: function () {
                    var template = _.template($('#user-details-template').html(), {});
                    this.$el.html(template);
                }
            });
            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'new': 'editUser',
                'users/:id': 'userInfo',
                'edit/:id': 'editUser',
                }
            });

            var userList = new UserList();
            var editUser = new EditUser();
            var userInfo = new UserInfo();
            var router = new Router();
            router.on('route:home', function () {
                userList.render();
            });
            router.on('route:editUser', function (id) {
                editUser.render({id: id});
            });
            router.on('route:userInfo', function () {
                console.log('show details');
                userInfo.render();
            });
            Backbone.history.start();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem's not with your client code, but something's off with the server.

You can check that by just doing the GETs from your browser - the [list GET](http://mywebbdesigner.com/adressbook/users) works fine but the [item GET](http://mywebbdesigner.com/adressbook/users/1) is failing.  The [original server.js](https://github.com/thomasdavis/video-backbone-beginner-server/blob/master/server.js) looks fine, so I'd suggest first double-checking that the one on your server is the same, then if that's not it, focus on the userDetails() function to see if you can find why that fails, probably by running the server.js locally...

Comment: yes, the list GET works, but the item GET and POST is failing. I have the same code locally. both locally and on the testsite the error is the same. Cannot GET, 404

Comment: How are you serving it locally?

I just installed node.js & redis locally, ran up redis then ran 'node server.js', pointed your client code to the Node.js server on localhost:3000 and it worked as expected...

Comment: I installed a yeoman bower workflow and started a grunt server.. still not sure why it's failing

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Grunt, so can't help more other than to suggest you give Node.js a try as the server, then you'd at least have a working baseline to compare against. (You'd either need to serve the html/css from elsewhere and use the ajaxPrefilter, or tweak the server.js to also serve the static files via something like "app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));").